Error en Rasberry pi 4 docker-compose up -d
Al ejecutar en raspberry pi 4: docker-compose up -d (muestra el siguiente error): ¿a que puede ser debido?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module> sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main  command_func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options return get_project(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 124, in docker_client
    kwargs = kwargs_from_env(environment=environment, ssl_version=tls_version)
TypeError: kwargs_from_env() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_version'


Quizá relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77641240/getting-docker-compose-typeerror-kwargs-from-env-got-an-unexpected-keyword-ar
